# UR10 state/real time interface

Tags: ros, state, ur10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I work on an UR5 with ROS Indigo and the following in my workspace:
universal robot: https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/tree/indigo
modern driver: https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver.git

Everything works fine (rviz, movement in simulation and on real robot), but can someone tell me how I can get joint position and voltages across the system state and in realtime?

Thank you!
Eva

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255313/ur10-state/real-time-interface/) by [ewka](https://answers.ros.org/users/29448/ewka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> how I can get joint position

Subscribe to the `/joint_states` topic.

> voltages across the system state

I'm not entirely sure what you mean here, but I'm pretty sure those are currently not published. If they are part of the datastreams on either the secondary or "matlab" interface, then they could be made available, but you'll have to add publishers for them yourself.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ewka](https://answers.ros.org/users/29448/ewka/) on 2017-02-22**:
Thanks for your fast answer!

What I mean is, that I have connected an analog sensor to the robot and I need the changing voltage (changing distance measurement) of the sensor (like on the UR panel) in ROS. So I can transform the voltage to distance.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-22**:
Well my answer remains the same: the current driver does not publish the values of the analog inputs, so you'll have to add that. See [ur_modern_driver#83](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/issues/83) for a related issue, and preferably discuss your plans with the maintainer.

**Comment by [MRJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29770/mrj/) on 2017-03-21**:
Have you found a solution of your problem? I have the same one...